# React Modify value being displayed without changing the value of input form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I've got an input field that wants to display currency. I want to display things based on the current local (which I'm using React-intl to accomplish). The issue with this is that their FormatNumber method returns a string and I need my value, on submit, to be an integer. I don't have access to or control over submit functionality so I would like to be able to have my input field maintain some sort of internal state that is constantly a float while at the same time displaying that float as a string from React-intl's formatNumber. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this comes late, but it may help others.

I'm using the onFocus and onBlur events to set this.state.isFocus, and use that in the render() to display either the amount or the formatNumber(), which displays it in currency format.

Hope this helps.